# How to know which line of code was being executed when a signal is received

Tags: interrupt, perl

I'm trying to do something like this

```
$SIG{ALRM} = sub {
    print $line_number_when_alarm_went_off;
};

alarm 10;

# rest of the script
```

I'm using `ALRM` as an example, I will end up using a different signal to kill from the outside to trigger it. Is there a neat way of doing this sort of operation?

I have some slow scripts and sometimes I would like to send them a signal to know where the code is at that moment.

I want to make this as unobtrusive as possible so I could package it and add it to legacy code.

Comment: It sounds like you're reinventing profiling. Have you tried [Devel::NYTProf](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::NYTProf)?

Comment: Just call `Carp::cluck` in the signal handler and get the whole stack trace.

Comment: cluck does work as well. i had tried confess before but that didn't work, didnt occur to me to try cluck.

Comment: `confess` also calls exit. `cluck :: confess` as `warn :: die`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`caller`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/caller.html) in list context to get the package, file and line number of the place that the current sub got called from.

```
$SIG{ALRM} = sub {
    my ($pkg, $file, $line) = caller;

    CORE::say $line;
    die;
};

alarm 2;

while (1) {
    1;
}
```

This will output `11` (if I counted correctly, in my file it's 1740, and the `$SIG` line is 1730.

It also works with other signal handlers, like `warn`.

```
$SIG{__WARN__} = sub {
    my ($pkg, $file, $line) = caller;

    CORE::say $line;
};

warn 'foo';
```

This will output `7`

Note that your code has a syntax error. You are assigning a *hash reference* as a signal handler, **not a sub reference**!

Comment: i have been googling for hours and somehow caller never popped up. this is exactly what i was looking for, thank you!

what hash reference ? sub{ ... } returns a sub reference, this code works for me

Comment: @null maybe you need to get more Google foo :-) I first thought of `__LINE__` but that obviously have the current line. So this solution became obvious.

Comment: ahh, i see my question was edited. you are right! i missed the "sub" part!